# Django. Подтянуть новости из linkedin

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, есть ли у кого пример, как подтянуть новости, который опубликовывает пользователь в LinkedIn? Как это провернуть?

Comment: Может бы там есть RSS?

Comment: Не нашел RSS. Я думал можно как-нибудь через приложение, которое я создал в linked.

Comment: RSS они закрыли походу.